# Visual Studio 2013 C++ outlining Collapsing issue

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, outlining

Recently I've been noticing the outlining in visual studio 2013 isn't working properly. It only happens for a few files but it is in specific areas. I've tried deleting the opensdf and sdf files, which correct me if I'm wrong, store the IntelliSense data. and the problems occur in exactly the same places when reopening the project.

Here is a GIF of it happening:
http://i.gyazo.com/fe50d268bf3a9de74a66bb6946b8765f.gif
the mouse appears to be more to the right than it actually is for some reason. I'm actually clicking on the plus and minus icons.

Is there anything in the code that could be causing this? because as the IntelliSense data was rebuilt the issue occurs in exactly the same place.

Has anyone else come across this bug before?

EDIT: another GIF of it happening in another bit of code: http://i.gyazo.com/0340484ee6dc0165bd334770d2dc0f0e.gif

Comment: So...what's the issue exactly (you don't actually describe it)? That your mouse is off or that all outlines are collapsed instead of just the first?

Comment: Sorry its hard to explain. What the problem is when i collapse certain methods it collapses a group of methods for some reason

Also notice the left side look at how the lines are: http://i.gyazo.com/3bc30a3e4f2b4ba97346fa8d66cb0448.png

Comment: Try separating all methods/functions by a blank line. That should fix collapsing more than the requested method. (Not including the attached comments)

Comment: @Casey Just tried it and it still collapses all of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so after alot of testing i worked out that it seemed the issue was a very strange bug with visual studio.

I deleted and recreated the file and it seems to be working now